# Minimum Time for Partially Sorted Array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

We are given a partially sorted array A, i.e. `for i=1, 2, ..., n-k` we have:

```
A[i]<= A[i+k]
```

For sorting array completely, we need at least `O(n log k)` time.

what is the condition and solution that make this axiom is true always?

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nearly-sorted-algorithm/

Comment: Where did you read this axiom?

Answer (score 1):

You can use shell sort from this problem.In this algorithm,After each phase and some increment hk, for every i, we have a[ i ] ≤ a [ i + hk ]. all elements spaced hk apart are sorted. This array is said to be hk – sorted. output of shell sort is 1-sorted.
if array is k-sorted then shell sort need O(log k) for sort array completely. each phase need O(n) then total order is O(n log k).

Suppose we want to sort this array:

[image]

this array is 4-sorted (k=4). for sorting this, Is needed to 2 phases 
(h2 = 2, h3 = 1)
So two phases are needed (lg 4 or lg k).
At each phase, there are n/k sub arrays that must be sorted. every sub array sort with insertion sort. Order of sort each sub array is O(n).
Finally, Total order O(n*lg k) = O(n log k).

Comment: `if array is k-sorted then shell sort need O(log k) for sort array completely` - It would be good to show an idea of proof for that.

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph Please upvote and accept this answer if it helps you, so people know this is the correct answer and helps them.